# Deploy Sagemaker builtin Algo trained models (e.g. RCF) on a Multi-model endpoint

Tags: machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker

Good day,

Is it possible to use Sagemaker's builtin algo containers, specifically the one for RandomCutForest, for a Multi-model model entity/endpoint? Tried using the builtin images, and the error "does not contain required com.amazonaws.sagemaker.capabilities.multi-models=true" was encountered. From what I've read, it seems that I need to create a custom container/image and also reviewed the examples available (XGBoost MME, Bring your own MME), however, I can't find information on how to load the trained Random Cut forest models (model_algo-1.model.rcf).

If it's possible to use the builtin algo image (RCF) for Multi-model, can you point a documentation or maybe a hint on how to accomplish this.

Thanks,

Peter